# Is "Ubuntu Desktop for Developers" different from "Ubuntu Desktop"?

Tags: gcc, g++, xterm, gdb

Is "Ubuntu Desktop for Developers" different from "Ubuntu Desktop"?  If so, how do I download the Developers' version.  I want to make sure that I get things like gcc, g++, gdb, ddd, etc

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to [this page on ubuntu.com](https://ubuntu.com/desktop/developers), please note that it is only saying that Ubuntu is a good operating system for developers.

There is not an official flavor of Ubuntu that is called "Ubuntu Desktop for Developers", so there's no difference!

Comment: Also "developers" with a small `d`, not capitalized